# Using Python-Selenium for automation to download videos. I am unable to click an element. Tried all know methods to me

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

https://kickassanime.rs is a web-site that streams anime. I am making a bot (Using Selenium in Python) that downloads videos.
I am unable to click a button with a link-text " 1080P [Mp4]". I tried all possible methods that can help to click but that element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class autoDownload:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get('https://kickassanime.rs')
        self.action = ActionChains(self.driver)

    def sign_in(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Signin/Signup').click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__BVID__225"]').send_keys('john443255@gmail.com') #Not real real, You can use this one to quick sign-in.
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__BVID__226"]').send_keys('KissAnime@123')
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modalSignIn___BV_modal_body_"]/form/div[4]/div/button').click()

    def search_anime(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="anime-search-input"]').click()
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="anime-search-input"]').send_keys('Black Clover' + Keys.ENTER)
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Black Clover (TV)').click()

    def from_episodes(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__BVID__53"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]').click()

    def download(self):
        a = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(' 1080P [Mp4]')
        a.click()
        '''
        (or...)

        self.action.context_click(a).perform()  # Things later I want to practice
        '''


bot = autoDownload()
bot.sign_in()
bot.search_anime()
bot.from_episodes()
bot.download()
```

problem's on **download()** function.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @mkhurmi I am getting an 'unable to locate element' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unable to locate element because that element is in an iframe. And its not a simple iframe, but a nested one. You have to switch to that nested iframe first in order to click on the download link.

```
    outerFrame=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'/mobile2') and @class='embed-responsive-item']"))
    driver.switch_to_frame(outerFrame) //Frame 1
    driver.switch_to_frame("id1-item") // Nested Frame
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#divDownload a").click() //link to download
    driver.switch_to_default_content() // switch back to default page
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your Solution and I apologize for late reply. I was trying your solution and practiced it on my code, It still has some error.. Now it says "NoSuchFrameException: Message: //iframe[contains(@src,'/mobile')]", I also tried to fix errors by my self, but I failed. Please Help Me. I don't want to give up on this program.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please chec. It works fine at my end. Please upvote and mark tick if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks....... Your solution worked. Your The Best Programmer.